# I can't delete my first node and it will crash when I insert the number that no in list

Tags: c++

I can't delete my first node and it will crash when I insert the number that no in list. Please help.

Here is my declare:

```
struct node
{
char student_name[40];
char student_gender[40];
char student_course[40];
int student_number;
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
}*newnode, *studentlist,*temp;

char name[40];
char gender[40];
char course[40];
int number = 0;
char selection[4];
int s;
int a;
char student_number[20];
```

Here is my code:

```
void delete_student(){     

temp=studentlist;
printf("Enter the number of student to delete\n");
fgets(student_number,20,stdin);
a = atoi (student_number);

if (studentlist == NULL)
printf("list is empty\n");

else if (a==studentlist->student_number)

        studentlist=studentlist->next;
    else
    {
        temp=studentlist;
        while(a != temp->student_number)

    {

            temp->prev=temp;
            temp=temp->next;

}
temp->prev->next=temp->prev->next->next;
}
  printf("Delete success\n");
  printf("Press any key to go back main menu\n");
  getch();

  }
```

Another problem is when I make a deletion, my show list from back will also bug. It continues non stop loop. How can i fix it too?

```
    void show_list_from_last(){

temp = studentlist;

if (studentlist == NULL)
    printf("List is empty\n");
else
{
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    do
    {
        printf("student name   = %s", temp->student_name);
        printf("student gender = %s", temp->student_gender);
        printf("student course = %s", temp->student_course);
        printf("Student Number = %d\n\n", temp->student_number);
        temp = temp->prev;
    } while (temp != NULL);
}
printf("\n\nPress any key to go back main menu\n");
getch();
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? and analyze it step by step?

Comment: debugger?
what was it?
i analyze it step by step ard...i cant figure out what problem inside.

Comment: then start from getting to know any debugger, or learn using printf for the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

Issues that I see:

1. You have:

   ```
   temp=studentlist;
   ```

   I didn't see the type specifier for `temp`.
2. You have:

   ```
   else if (a==studentlist->student_number)
       studentlist=studentlist->next;
   ```

   Here, you are leaving `temp` still in the list. `temp->next` still points to `studentlst` and `studentlist->prev` still points to `temp`.
3. You have:

   ```
   while(a != temp->student_number)
   {
      temp->prev=temp;
      temp=temp->next;
   }
   ```

   Why do you need the line `temp->prev=temp;`? You are just looking for the node that contains the item. There is no need to modify the list yet. Plus I haven't clearly thought through the side effects of that statement. You certainly don't need it. In addition, you are not taking care of the case where the item is not found in your list. In other words, you are not checking whether you've reached the end of the list.
4. When you get out of the above `while` loop, you are assuming that you have found the item. That is a bad assumption. You have to check whether you found the item before you try to change links using `temp`.

Here's a modified version of the function that I came up with. You will have to refine it since I don't know what type `temp` needs to be and whether you can use `delete temp;`.

```
 void delete_student()
 { 
    // What's the type of 'temp'? Node?
    temp=studentlist;
    printf("Enter the number of student to delete\n");
    fgets(student_number,20,stdin);
    a = atoi (student_number);

    if (studentlist == NULL)
       printf("list is empty\n");

    else if (a==studentlist->student_number)
    {
       studentlist=studentlist->next;
       studentlist->prev = NULL;

       // Need to deallocate temp.
       delete temp;
    }
    else
    {
       temp=studentlist;
       while( a != NULL && a != temp->student_number)
       {
          // Why do you need to set temp->prev ???
          // temp->prev=temp;
          temp=temp->next;
       }

       // What if we did not find the item?
       // Delete the item only if we find it.
       if ( temp )
       {
          // Unlink the node from the rest of the list.
          Node* prev = temp->prev;
          Node* next = temp->next;
          temp->prev = NULL;
          temp->next = NULL;
          if ( prev )
          {
             prev->next = next;
          }
          if ( next )
          {
             next->prev = prev;
          }

          // Delete the node that contains the item.
          delete temp;
       }
    }
    printf("Delete success\n");
    printf("Press any key to go back main menu\n");
    getch();

 }
```

Comment: temp is a node

i declare it at the beginning .

Comment: not very understand start from if(temp) there~ may make a edit?
i ard edit my post with declare ard~thx